# How to open a browser with a url including "&" from maven build

Tags: maven, url, build

I am using maven plug-in to open browser with a specific url. Following is the code snipped

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Run URL in system browser.</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <exec executable="start" vmlauncher="false">
                                    <arg line="http://localhost:9090/services/winnabunch/arisMoonFestival_html/launchgame?lang=en&playerToken=gaurav"/>
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
    </plugin>
```

All is going well except if I am adding "&" in the url it gives an error. Question is that how I can add "&" in the url?

Comment: Ever tried to use "&amp;" ? Why not using selenium driver for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` in your URL is interpreted as starting an entity reference.  To include a literal `&`, you'll need to write it as `&amp;` or `&#38;`:

```
<arg line="http://localhost:9090/services/winnabunch/arisMoonFestival_html/launchgame?lang=en&amp;playerToken=gaurav"/>
```

Further information at [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0026/index.htm).

Comment: I want to add a commect but StackOverflow tells me i have not enough reputation i need 50. 
I will edit the solution.

Comment: Thanks for adding some explanation - I've edited your post to add the missing terminator.